# x and y axis ticks shifted from origin

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have multiple plots stacked on each other and there is a common x-axis. The values for the x-axis run from 70 to 6225. When I try to give the range (50,6250), the output is from 50 to 6050 but 50 doesn't start at the origin. Moreover, it also doesn't end at  6250. How to accomplish this. I want the y axis ticks to run from the origin of one plot to the end of it before the next stack begins.

I have attached the MWE and image of the same

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import pylab 
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

def fit_data():

    fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(15,15))

    ax1= fig.add_subplot(811,)
    ax1.scatter(data1['D'], data1['F'],  marker='o', color='red', s=15)
    ax1.errorbar(data1['D'], data1['F'], data1['eF'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='red', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(812, sharex=ax1 )
    ax2.scatter(data2['D'], data2['F'],  marker='o', color='blue', s=15)
    ax2.errorbar(data2['D'], data2['F'], data2['eF'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='blue', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(813, sharex=ax1 )
    ax3.scatter(data3['D'], data3['F'],  marker='o', color='green', s=15)
    ax3.errorbar(data3['D'], data3['F'], data3['eF'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='green', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(814, sharex=ax1 )
    ax4.scatter(data4['D'], data4['F'],  marker='o', color='sienna', s=15)
    ax4.errorbar(data4['D'], data4['F'], data4['eF'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='sienna', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax5 = fig.add_subplot(815, sharex=ax1 )
    ax5.scatter(data5['D'], data5['F'],  marker='o', color='brown', s=15)
    ax5.errorbar(data5['D'], data5['F'], data5['eF'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='brown', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax6 = fig.add_subplot(816, sharex=ax1 )
    ax6.scatter(data6['D'], data6['F'],  marker='o', color='gold', s=15)
    ax6.errorbar(data6['D'], data6['F'], data6['eF'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='gold', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax7 = fig.add_subplot(817, sharex=ax1 )
    ax7.scatter(data7['D'], data7['F'],  marker='o', color='olive', s=15)
    ax7.errorbar(data7['D'], data7['F'], data7['eF'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='olive', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)

    ax8 = fig.add_subplot(818, sharex=ax1 )
    ax8.scatter(data8['D'], data8['F'],  marker='o', color='greenyellow', s=15)
    ax8.errorbar(data8['D'], data8['F'], data8['eF'], fmt='.', ecolor='black',color='greenyellow', elinewidth=1,capsize=3)
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0) # remove vertical space between subplots

    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='red', marker='o', markersize=5, label='1350 $\AA$')
    ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue', marker='o', markersize=5, label='1450 $\AA$')
    ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='green', marker='o', markersize=5, label='1710 $\AA$')
    ax3.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='sienna', marker='o', markersize=5, label='1800 $\AA$')
    ax4.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='brown', marker='o', markersize=5, label='2425 $\AA$')
    ax5.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='gold', marker='o', markersize=5, label='2625 $\AA$')
    ax6.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='olive', marker='o', markersize=5, label='2875 $\AA$')
    ax7.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])
    red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='orange', marker='o', markersize=5, label='3025 $\AA$')   
    ax8.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0, handles=[red_line])

    for ax in [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax5,ax6,ax7]:
        ax.tick_params('x', bottom=False, labelbottom=False)

    ax8.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
    ax8.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(50,6250))



    plt.savefig("all.jpeg")
    plt.savefig("all.pdf")
    fig.set_size_inches(w=15,h=15)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

fit_data()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want tick labels on every subplot or only the last one?

Comment: ticks for all the plots but the label (50, 550, 1050 ....) only for the bottom most plot. also want the plots to start and end at the values I have specified.

Answer (score 0):

To set the limits for the subplots you can do

```py
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8]:
    ax.set_xlim([50, 6250])
```

and setting the ticks to the desired sequence (50, 550, 1050, ...) can be done with

```py
ax8.set_xticks(np.arange(50, 6250, 500))
```

Or to include the end point you can use

```py
np.hstack([np.arange(50, 6250, 500), [6250]])
```

Comment: I have tried this ax8.set_xticks(np.arange(50, 6250, 500) but the reslut was still the same.

Comment: Can the plot have x axis starting from 50 and ending at 6250 at the ends like how we do in a graph sheet?

Comment: @BRMBU There was a typo, it should be `ax8.set_xticks(np.arange(50, 6250, 500))`

Comment: @BRMBU Take a look at the edited answer for how to include the endpoint in the xticks